# PHP: How to create html container helper?

Tags: php, html

For example, I have a list with very specific formatting that I want to put different content in over and over.

So I might have a function:

```
<?
function fancy_container (contents_array) {
  <?
    <ul>
      <? for($contents_array as $content) { ?>
        <li class='special'><? echo $content ?><div class='other-specials'></div></li>
      <? } ?>
    </ul>
  ?>
}
?>
```

That works, but I want to call it like this:

```
<?
  fancy_container(array(?>
    <div class='whatever'>hi there</div>
    <div class='whatever'>hi there</div>
    <div class='whatever'>hi there</div>
  <?), ?>
    <div class='other-junk'>hiya</div>
    <div class='other-junk'>hiya</div>
    <div class='other-junk'>hiya</div>
  <?))
?>
```

I figured out how to do this with a heredoc but that seems sort of nasty.  Am I going about this the wrong way?   I'm not a php guy so I'm not familiar with the normal way of doing things or limitations.  I know how to do this using ruby yield, but no idea in php.

I just want to inject html content into a container (or containers) and I want to have html be html, not heredoc text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Martin Lyne mentioned, it's a bit backwards and I guess an odd way of doing things. Probably more so because your intentionally not showing the full extent of the final usage. Here's your code cleaned up and made to be a bit more sane. You had syntax errors and a few stuff is just not allowed in PHP like how your calling the function.

```
<?php

function fancy_container ($contents_array) {

    if (!is_array($contents_array) || empty($contents_array)) {
        return '';
    }

    $output = '';
    $output .= '<ul>'.PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($contents_array as $content) {
        $output .= '<li class="special">'.$content.'<div class="other-specials"></div></li>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $output .= '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;

    return $output;

}

$contents = array();

ob_start();
?>

    <div class="whatever">hi there</div>
    <div class="whatever">hi there</div>
    <div class="whatever">hi there</div>

<?php

$contents[] = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
?>

    <div class="other-junk">hiya</div>
    <div class="other-junk">hiya</div>
    <div class="other-junk">hiya</div>

<?php
$contents[] = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

echo fancy_container($contents);

?>
```

### Outputs markup

```
<ul>
<li class="special">
    <div class="whatever">hi there</div>
    <div class="whatever">hi there</div>
    <div class="whatever">hi there</div>

<div class="other-specials"></div></li>
<li class="special">    
    <div class="other-junk">hiya</div>
    <div class="other-junk">hiya</div>
    <div class="other-junk">hiya</div>

<div class="other-specials"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ob_start, ob_get_contents, ob_end_clean are exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.  However I'm surprised at your rewrite of fancy_container where you remove the explicit html content and instead build html out of strings.

Comment: Also regarding both of your stances that what I'm doing is backward, I guess I don't understand what is backward about having a container that is complicated (aka, you don't want to repeat it all over) that you want to insert arbitrarily complicated html into.   The small example martin provided didn't address this case at all so I don't know what the correct way you have in mind would be but I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not just put the div tag there, instead of in your php function? If you must have style affected by PHP I'd recommend a PHP function that spits out a class `<div class="<?php echo getClass();?>">..content..</div>`

Comment: Are you referring to the 'other-specials' divs?  This is just a simple example.  Sometimes it is about a lot more than just a different class.  For example a container that is repeated with different content might itself have a complicated dom structure.   I just want to abstract out the part that changes and have a container function that only handles the stuff that is always the same.

Comment: In any case, forget about whether you think my *example* should be refactored.  I just need to know if/how I can best get html content from one function into another.   Is that possible or not?

Comment: It seems you are going backwards, from HTML to PHP, normally youd use PHP to build HTML from data (so your lists would be in arrays and they get spat out). The only way i can think of you being able to manipulate that HTML cleanly is with heredoc as you already say. Unless the HTML can be put in a separate file and read in piece by piece. Thrown together like partials then your higher level containers can be more abstract.

Comment: In this case the content in the lists is not just simple data.  It is complicated markup itself.